# Do gadgets/fetishes expire at the end of the session they are created?

Tags: savage-worlds, deadlands-reloaded

In Savage Worlds and Deadlands Reloaded, do gadgets and fetishes (made with the Gadgeteer  and Fetish Creator Edges) remain between sessions if they have PP remaining? Meaning if I make an item each session, can I slowly collect a hoard of gadgets, assuming they all still have PP?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Clint Black, official rules manager for *Savage Worlds*, [answered this succinctly](http://archive.pegforum.com/viewtopic.php?f=56&t=41782&p=395767&hilit=gadgeteer#p395767) on the Pinnacle forums:

> > If the power points reserves are not fully used, is the gizmo available in the next session, or does it last until the end of the session it was created?
>
> It only lasts for the session it was created.

So yes, they do expire at the end of the session, and it is not possible to hoard gadgets/fetishes.